# Will the Intel Bay Trail CPU problem be fixed in 17.04?

Tags: kernel, intel

Many people have problems with Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10 where the system freezes completely, and I am one of them.

I want to know whether Ubuntu 17.04 will fix that issue or not, whether it has already been fixed on the trial ISO image of 17.04, before I try to download it and test it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### TL;DR - my research suggests it's not fixed in the 17.04 beta image or in the release, but I have high hopes for 17.10.

These freezes happen when the processor attempts to enter a low-power state (c-state) that the kernel does not support. This problem was introduced by

```
commit 8fb55197e64d5988ec57b54e973daeea72c3f2ff
Date:   Tue Apr 7 16:20:28 2015 +0100
drm/i915: Aggressive downclocking on Baytrail
```

This went upstream in kernel 4.2, and we have been having issues since then. As explained in [heynnema's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/883431/527764) (and [this post where I have tried to collate information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)) there is a straightforward and effective workaround, passing a boot parameter that disables the low power states.

The beta version of 17.04 currently available uses 4.9 (it's based on the upstream 4.9.6 as I understand), and by the time the release comes out in April, I believe [it will be using 4.10](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-developers-still-tracking-linux-kernel-4-10-for-ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus-512544.shtml). The problem still exists in these kernels, so I have concluded that it is **not fixed as of now**. I checked the Ubuntu kernel changelogs, and found nothing, but please correct me if I am wrong.

I have been tracking the [c-state bug here on kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) for a long time. In January 2017, Mika Kuoppala added [this patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051#c683) to the thread. Apparently, it reverts the earlier commit that caused the problem. The patch is called

```
drm/i915/byt: Avoid tweaking evaluation thresholds
```

Testing indicates very good results with this patch, which was submitted to the i915 driver owners on 25th January. <del>All being well, it could be merged in the 4.11 window. The 4.11 kernel may be released around the end of April.</del> **A version of this patch was merged in the 4.11 window and reports indicate that the bug is fixed in 4.11.**

Each of the troublesome BayTrail processors behaves a little bit differently with each different kernel. In 16.04 (4.4 kernel) my uptime on Atom Z3735F without the intel_idle parameter was around 15 minutes before freezing. I tested the beta 17.04 ISO in live mode, and I didn't get a freeze in 90 minutes, so it seems like I'm lucky with this kernel. You can do the same thing to test any image on your system - just make a bootable USB and "try Ubuntu without installing" and test it for as long as possible.

When 17.04 came out, I installed it, and in the first two weeks I ran it without the `intel_idle` parameter, I only had three c-state freezes, which is a huge improvement on earlier versions.

The safest thing to do is use the boot parameter. Based on my research I am expecting the bug to be fixed in 17.10 (and in other distro releases later this year) which will be using a kernel >=4.11, but **not** in 17.04.

However, there's always the possibility that the Ubuntu Kernel Team may patch it themselves. If you can tolerate running an unstable system occasionally, you can watch for progress by running regular updates (`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`) and testing each new kernel without the boot parameter when it arrives. You can also [read the changelogs as new packages are installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272215/seeing-apt-get-changelogs-for-to-be-upgraded-packages) or (again, if you can tolerate instability) [install a mainline kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).

Comment: Thank you Zanna, it always happening with the bay trail Gpu , and the code to fix it don't work with many and i am one , so i asked about it, sorry that my question didn't tell that it with Gpu.

Comment: The problem also as you said with bay trail cpu , it's also with bay trail gpu and at me with the gpu, my cpu is intel pentium, but my gpu is intel bay trail , any way the problem with bay trail cause the same issuse ,freezes

Comment: @Bassem actually that was my fault, it was my edit to your question - I didn't know about issues with a gpu (btw some of the BayTrail series are Pentium). I think the problem is in the same driver, `i915`, so likely to be fixed by the same patch, but the bug report is about problems fixed by the intel_idle parameter and if that doesn't work for you it is a different bug according to the kernel folks. Can you please provide a bug report or forum thread (you say others share your problem) where I can find out more, so I can advise you what to do next? (I think you may need to ask a new question)

Comment: Thank you Zanna , and sorry cause i didn't recieved email by your comments, I don't know why , My profile option is to recieve

Comment: You can search by , Ubuntu freeze, or how to fix Ubuntu freeze, you will find that this issuse with the bay trail, and the fix didn't work for me, maybe your one can work, but my laptop is dell inspiron 5551, ram 4 , cpu intel pentium 2.4 catch 4 , gpu intel bay trail, so i knew it's the gpu, and if you didn't find i will send you links to others, my swap always 10 so it's good for 4G

Comment: @Bassem the specs are [here](https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201501-16349/) and they say it has the Pentium N3540 CPU which is [definitely affected by the c-state bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail). When I search I only find Bay Trail CPU (I have been following the issue for a long time myself, and never heard about any separate GPU problem) so please do give me a link if you can. Are you sure you applied the boot parameter correctly? N3540 does respond to it...

Comment: I am trying now to find the link that i used it's roots to fix the problem when it happend , he said it's gpu by trail problems so i didn't asked that time, and my gpu that bay trail not my cpu, think that cpu is good but may be it's the reason , the laptop worked good with windows ms 8.1 , and ubuntu 14.04 worked good with gigabyte g31 , but with laptop after weeks must freezes while it running every short or long time , and must resrart to can run it, maybe the cpu the reason but that i found when i searched that time said gpu bay trail issuse, will try to find it , cause that was months ago

Comment: Your CPU is Bay Trail @Bassem and it is one that has this bug and causes freezing, unless the specs I find online are not the right ones. But you say the intel_idle fix does not work for you and that concerns me. Are you 100% sure it does not work? You typed it exactly correct and ran `sudo update-grub` etc?

Comment: yes i am sure , i found 2 of the question that said in comment that it was graphics problems but not bay trail that i saw , i am trying to find it , and will try your roots again but when it happen cause it's happen with 14.04 weeks after install and update , but with 16.04 after boot , and can't type any thing and can't log in it on laptop , after install always freezes no way to type or try to fix , and no bugs report to send , you can make the question cpu or i can do that , till i find the others http://askubuntu.com/questions/778045/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-often

Comment: other one with rots but not i found before http://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly

Comment: @Bassem graphics driver issues can cause similar freezing (usually nvidia though) but the very famous Bay Trail bug is known to be a CPU problem and fixed by this boot parameter. Your CPU is Bay Trail, and does have this bug, but since the intel_idle param does not work for you, it seems that you have a different and unusual bug (instead or as well), which may be related to your BayTrail GPU, or could be due to something else :( Since this question was edited, answered and voted on as relating to the CPU issue...

Comment: ... and is of very great interest to many people as CPU issue I am very grateful to you for editing it. I recommend that you try the beta image of 17.04 in live mode on your device. For me it is much more stable than 16.04 and you may see some improvement as well. See my answer here [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](//askubuntu.com/a/803649) for how to add the parameter before logging in (see the end of the answer) @Bassem

Comment: this one also gpu intel , but not i tried it's roots before , http://askubuntu.com/questions/771932/ubuntu-16-04-freeze-crash  if it not found it must be edited or removed , so , thank you for your help here , i will wait the final 17.04 to try it, and will close this question now with your answer and will try to cancel update for new 14.04 till it out, or will try the code again on it when start to crush and freeze, cause i always install fresh one every time after lot freezes start

Comment: Yes and i posted it as CPU, but was also Gpu i found before, now can't find it, i did't saved it cause it didn't fixed the problem, thank you again

Comment: @Bassem thank you for your help :) If you want to ask a new question about your problem, please first try again adding the boot parameter permanently so that you can say it does not work on the latest kernel etc, otherwise someone will answer with the same thing. The linked post is interesting. You can check also the [Arch wiki page on Intel Graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics) which has some more tips for solving issues (it also mentions using this boot parameter)

Comment: Thank you again, my fresh Ubuntu started to freezing during work after 3 or 4 days , now i tried your solve and i needed heynnema's answer also to can open the text file and edit it, till now no freezes and if it did i will tell you, hope that 17,04 will fix it , regards.

Comment: The bug report has new comment # 1013 stating bug has been fixed in current kernels.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a freezing issue on 20.04 :(

Answer (score 7):

There is a fix for this in [How to set intel_idle.max_cstate=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749349/how-to-set-intel-idle-max-cstate-1).

---

In `terminal`, type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to include this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

then do:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

---

This is an Intel problem, not a Ubuntu problem, but thank goodness that we've got a fix.

Nobody knows if Ubuntu 17.04 will require this fix or not.

Comment: This is just a workaround though (and we have many posts about it), I also want to know if it will be fixed in 17.04. It's a kernel problem really, since Intel can't fix hardware retroactively

Comment: @Zanna - As far as I'm aware, it will never be incorporated into the kernel directly, but be available as a boot flag.  From what I can find, there is a lot of debate over it though.  There's an open bug on [kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051).  Maybe that can shed some light on the subject?

Comment: @ThatGuy tell me about it, I've been following that bug for a year. If you read it, you see that Linus himself wrote a patch for earlier kernels. I also know of, and have tested, a kernel patch written specifically for my device that fixes the problem completely, so I am putting faith in the kernel devs to fix it properly some day.

Comment: I agree with Zanna as is often the case :)

Comment: @Zanna - I hope so too. It'd be nice to have Ubuntu on my tablet without any Kernel patching. :)

Comment: @ThatGuy read the newer messages in the report and it looks promising - I'm expecting the fix to go upstream in 4.11

Comment: @Zanna - Do you think they'll move to 4.11+ in 17.04?

Comment: No, I don't think so @ThatGuy it will be released with 4.10 and it's 4.9 now (see my answer)

Comment: thank you all Heynnema , Zanna and Thatguy , Zanna is true , it's kernel problem and just with bay trail gpu

Comment: That fix was working good on Ubuntu 14.04 , but on 17.4 even after made it , it still cause freeze some times

Comment: @Bassem Check your typing. Did you remember to do the `sudo update-grub` and reboot? If so, you may have a new problem. Ask a new question, give whatever new details might apply, put in a link to this question, and note that you've applied the Bay Trail patch already.

Comment: yes i took it ctrl+c copy as every time , and then past to terminal, i will ask new question , thank you

Comment: This makes it a lot more stable but after a few weeks, or sometimes even a few months, it still freezes. This I am now trying with cstate=0 to see if that helps - may take a few months to check!

Answer (score 1):

According to comment# 1013 in [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) it is now fixed:

> I haven't checked this thread in a long time, but I thought I should
>   post my findings just in case it is of any use to anyone.
>
> A low end computer powered with an Intel N2807 which never worked more
>   than 30 mn without crashing when I didn't set ...max_cstates=1 now
>   works perfectly well with a stock kernel v. 5.3.1 or 4.19.75. I ran it
>   for a couple of days with each version without any issues. The average
>   power consumption was also down by a little over 10%.

It has taken about four years to fix this bug first reported December 8, 2015.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 you should use the command at the following link because this way here will not work with it  <<<       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048955/ubuntu-18-04-freeze/1048956#1048956

Comment: It's unfortunately still not fixed, sometimes the system works for a few weeks or even months but sooner or later it freezes :( - even with cstates=1 - I am now trying with cstates=0 to see if that makes any difference.