# Is this bug (Intel BayTrail Freeze) fixed in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: intel, cpu, 17.10

I want to know, if this bug is fixed, because all previous versions of Ubuntu didn't work for me. So I just want to know, should i leave Windows 10 and go for Ubuntu 17.10. Thanks!

[Will the Intel Bay Trail CPU problem be fixed in 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883430/will-the-intel-bay-trail-cpu-problem-be-fixed-in-17-04/884128#884128)

Comment: I would suggest what Zanna said here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883430/will-the-intel-bay-trail-cpu-problem-be-fixed-in-17-04/884128#comment1378351_883430

Comment: I know about idle parameter but it kills my notebook battery :( That's why I am asking

Comment: @mikewhatever nvm, stayed on windows. Ubuntu 17.10 lags too much. :(

Comment: *Has this particular bug been fixed?* is not generally a question of opinion. I am voting to reopen this.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, and I have Intel BayTrail graphics. No freezes encountered so far.

The patch mentioned in the linked post was merged in kernel 4.11 and is still present in kernel 4.13, which 17.10 uses.

While this may not fix the problem for all BayTrail devices, it's widely reported to have improved or fixed this issue.

Comment: There's no point running 17.10 on a baytrail device. It lags way too much as op said. I have one too and can confirm. Better stick to windows or using a distro with  a DE like mate, cinnamon, or xfce instead of whatever 17.10's default it.

Comment: @answerSeeker that might be due to low specs of the device. All BayTrail is not the same. FTR I use Ubuntu MATE on my Bay Trail machine. The 17.10 version runs well with no freezes so far. I only have 2GB RAM and that's why I stick to lighter DEs...

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I meant. If you stick to stock Ubuntu, you'll suffer lags. But I'm using mine with win10 cuz I get the best performance there.