# Ubuntu 18.04 freeze

Tags: 18.04

I purchased and received a Gazelle Ubuntu 18.04 laptop sixteen days ago. It was great until June 21, 2018. Now everything is frozen, icons/apps/ windows, tabs, etc.

It began this behavior after my one and only update. Did I get a lemon or is this fixable?

Comment: I suggest taking the laptop to a service.

Answer (score 2):

I'd a similar problem. Try the following

1. make a copy of the grub config

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
   ```
2. open the file grub file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. search for a line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add the following parameter to this line

   ```
   intel_idle.max_cstate=1
   ```
4. update grub

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. reboot

If it doesn't work delete the property and update grub again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I can not open ANYTHING, much less the file grub. Nothing is clickable.

Comment: Open a tty console with eg ctrl-alt-f3, login here in. Otherwise during the boot process enter grub - edit commandline and enter the grub property described.

Comment: This solution works only for Bay Trail CPUs and should be affected from the very beginning.